# How to highlight the selected tab in application using angular?

Tags: angular

I am new to angular I need to highlight the selected tab while changing the URL.

```
<div class="header-sub-nav">
    <nav>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let tab of menuData">
            <a   [routerLink]="tab.routerLink" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">{{tab.menuTitle}}</a>
         </ng-container>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: put the routing module and the menuData array.

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup the router module. The routes in the router module need to match with the links in the menuData array.

Here is a simple example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jp4rjn

I updated the example. With that you should be able to solve it.

Comment: those are completed thank you.
but i need box around highlighted tab.
https://xd.adobe.com/view/a5512b83-f309-4505-7a8e-c41abd7bc726-d360/screen/f57f1121-0334-476d-a541-a0413b400dc9/SRP-File-Upload-Key-Retrieval-2-2?fullscreen


Please look into above link